# clearing screen after CGContextDrawImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying for a image relaterd i-phone application.I am using a line of code

```
    CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
```

I am working with multiple images.So i want to clear the screen after this .Any built in function using for this (Like in C we can use cleardevice in graphics).Any help appreciating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [CGContextFillRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17024) - just set the rect to be the whole view and the brush to be solid white :)

---

For example, to clear the image you just drew with white :

```
const CGFloat white[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
CGContextSetFillColor(context1, white);
CGContextFillRect(context1, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, hight));
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using CG... methods instead of just UIImageViews ?

Comment: I want to take all the pixel values in a image .thats what i am using CG.for storing pixels i am using a unsigned char *rawImgData;Can you sujest me some methods to delete all data in rawImgData while interacting with second image.I am using malloc and free functions for my code ..still cant figure out the bug.

Comment: If it's just a C array then memset should clear it to all zeros - `memset(rawImgData, 0, length);`?